# Django Docker app container don't open on browser after run

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I dockerize my django app, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apk add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN mkdir /Code
WORKDIR /Code
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /Code/

ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

well, i build my image and I run it:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --link postgres:postgres cath11/test_app
```

all seems to be done:

[image]

but when I open my browser on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/ my app does not open

[image]

Why my django app seems running on my container, I expose port but I cannot see it in my hosted browser?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on Windows?  If so, are you using either Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine, or are you using the native Docker Desktop application?

Comment: now i am using Docker toolbox on my mac

Answer (score 3):

Use `docker-machine ip default` to check for the IP, and use it instead of `localhost`. 
Technically, the django app is served inside the container, not your local host.

So in your case, you should try `http://<ip from the command>:8000/`

Comment: seem to work, but how can i link internal ip to my external host for using 127.0.0.1 instead of docker internal? thanks

Comment: You might need to redirect your local IP to the docker IP. But that would be hack-ish. Why would you want to do that though?